# I'm not able to return member list and memberOf list of LDAP group

Tags: c#, .net, ldap

I'm trying to get all groups and their related sub groups and members from LDAP.

I'm using this code :

```
public List<Group> GetGroups()
{
        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://someLdap.com");
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(de);
        searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group))";
        searcher.PageSize = 500;

        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memeber"); 
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memeberOf");
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

        List<Group> groups;
        using (SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll())
        {
            int count = 1;
            groups = new List<Group>();

            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                Group group = new Group();
                if (result == null) continue;
                Console.WriteLine(count++); // just to print 

                group.Name = result.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString();
                group.Description = result.Properties["description"][0].ToString();
                ResultPropertyValueCollection valueCollection =
                    result.Properties["memeber"];
                foreach (var user in valueCollection)
                {
                    group.Users.Add(user.ToString());
                }

                groups.Add(group);
            }
        }
        return groups;
    }
```

The code only works with `sAMAccountName` and `description`

But I'm not able to get all `member` and `memberOf` values

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, `member` and `memberOf` are **multi-valued** properties - they may contain **more than one value** - so therefore you cannot just assign them to a single variable....

Comment: Thank you Marc_s your comments helped me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have misspelt both attribute names throughout your code and your post.

Comment: @rojo Cut the comedy thanks. These attributes don't have arbitrary names: they are predefined in schemas. You can't just mis-spell them at whim.

Comment: Ok Thank you EJP, i diffently misspelt both attributes